# Android application modular design

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is more of a android design question. I am building an application that is going to consist of features such as P2P Connection, Location Receiving/Updates and a few others.

My applications current design is an activity consisting of two fragments in a viewpager and under a toolbar.

My first approach was to write different features all in separate classes (E.g Location receiver in its own class, a Google map generator in another) and then instantiate these objects where I needed them. I started to realize that that method wasn't working.

An idea I had was to implement everything I need in my fragments "onCreateView()" method but that just seems disorderly.

My question is where exactly do we implement certain features?

Here is an example of the fragment consisting of a map.

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{

SupportMapFragment mSupportMapFragment;
int radius = 20;
double mLatitude;
double mLongitude;

public double getLatitude() {
    return mLatitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    return mLongitude;
}

private GoogleMap maps;
     @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mSupportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager sfm = getFragmentManager();
    mSupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    if(!mSupportMapFragment.isAdded())
    sfm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.map_frag,mSupportMapFragment).commit();

   else if(mSupportMapFragment.isAdded())
        sfm.beginTransaction().hide(mSupportMapFragment).commit();
    else
        sfm.beginTransaction().show(mSupportMapFragment).commit();







    LocationManager mLocationManager;
    LocationListener mLocationListener;
    mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {

                /*
                Updates to our map may need to be taken place here. Need to listen to other devices in the area.
                 */

                Log.e("Latitude: ", "" + location.getLatitude());
                Log.e("Longitude: ", "" + location.getLongitude());
                maps.clear(); //Clear the map of any  existing markers
                mLatitude = location.getLatitude();//Get coordinates stored into local variables
                mLongitude = location.getLongitude();

               LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLatitude,mLongitude);//Create a "LatLng" object consisting of these coordinates

                MarkerOptions mp1 = new MarkerOptions();//Instantiate a new "MarkerOptions" where we will be able to define a...
                                                        //...marker

                mp1.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),//Customizing marker...
                        location.getLongitude()));
                 mp1.title("You");
                maps.addMarker(mp1);//Finally add the marker to the map
                maps.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));//Move camera to markers location using our "latLng" variable
                maps.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));// Zoom, (between 2.0 - 21.0) the higher, the more zoomed in

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    };

    mLocationManager = (LocationManager)     getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,120000,radius,mLocationListener);


    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    maps = map;
 }
}
```

In this fragment alone I have established location updates and a google map API. Everything seems to be working so far.

My only concern is the design.
Is cramming all these features (and more to come) in a single fragment considered bad practice?

Comment: You can implement them on their own class. It will work. But we can't determine what is wrong until you include some of the codes. Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Aizen Edits have been made.

Comment: Ic, what you up to now. You can just use the class that you mentioned to create a constructor for a specific Listener class. Either way, if it is a Bad Practice or not, it is not a Big Bad Wolf in your code since even if you implement it in a different class, same stack of code will be called and no speed performance will actually differ. The only difference is, it looks messy. In Android coding, it is normal to encounter that, since almost everything in Android platform runs under different class that needs to be either override or implement. Just use the editor to hide big chunks of code.

Comment: Well, as long as the performance isn't affected. Still, organization would be great. Thanks for your answer though! @Aizen